# Using exception filtering in c# 6.0 (with typeof()) VS. catching custom exception

Tags: c#, exception, c#-6.0, custom-exceptions

I have a method for manage exception handling as below. The Question is that, in case that the `typeof` exception is our point, which approach is recommended? Using
`catch (System.Exception ex) when(ex.GetType() ==typeof(ExcOneException)){...}`
or
`catch (ExcOneException ex) {...}`

```
public T MyMethod<T>(Func<T> codeToExecute)
    {
        try
        {
            return codeToExecute.Invoke();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) when(ex.GetType() ==typeof(ExcOneException) )
        {
            throw new ExcOneException(ex.Message,ex);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ExcTwoException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** My solution has 3 projects, UI, Services and DataAccess. Each part has its own custom Exception-Handler class. Imagine that, the code in question is in service project. All codes should call this method for execution.  If there is any run-time error with type of ExcOneException, it means the error is in service section, else, there should be an error in data access part; so, ExcTwoException should be thrown. This approach helps me in bubbling error up to UI level with details. What I didn't know, was that, in the case that we can use C# 6 properties, when I have filtering just on exception type, which approach is better, using catch-when or mentioning exception type as argument of catch?

Comment: Why not `catch (System.Exception ex) when(ex is ExcOneException))`? In any case you should do `catch (ExcOneException ex) {...}`.

Comment: Exactly I want to know if there is any difference in execution and performance in this case, or not. I know for example, using if/else for checking type of exception in body of catch is not recommended because of stack-winding and loosing the trace. But I want to be sure if there is not any difference between two approaches mentioned in question, above.

Comment: Don't use `throw new ExcOneException(ex.Message,ex);` when the exception is already a ExcOneException. It recreates the stack trace. Use `throw;` as Paulo Morgado recommended

Answer (score 2):

**Simplification & Readability:**

You can filter with `is`, instead of `typeof`:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ExcOneException) { ... }
```

Chain multiple Exception types:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (ex is ExcOneException || ex is ExcTwoException) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you ever consider that? You mention performance. Do you have any measurements that make you suspicious.

Exception filters are there for filtering exceptions that you can't catch by type, which is not your case.

In your code you are, also, not re-throwing the caught exception. You are throwing an new exception with the caught exception as an inner exception which is what you do when you want to wrap the caught exception with a more meaningful one.

If you intention is to re-throw, the correct code is:

```
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't change my answer. I see no value in filtering on the exception type.

Comment: @PauloMorgado is correct, just throwing the exception back to the UI Layer will not reset the stack trace and this is the preferred approach for multi layered .NET Applications.